# How to call onclick listener in itself (in kotlin android dev)?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have a function:

```
ib_selectBackgroundImg.setOnClickListener {
        if(isPermissionsGranted){
            changeBackground()
        }
        else{
            validatePermissions()
        }
    }
```

When I click a button and the app doesn't have needed permissions, it asks the user for granting them. After that, changeBackground() function should be called.
I tried this:

```
ib_selectBackgroundImg.setOnClickListener {
        if(isPermissionsGranted){
            changeBackground()
        }
        else{
            validatePermissions()
            ib_selectBackgroundImg.callOnClick()
        }
    }
```

So, I have used **ib_selectBackgroundImg.callOnClick()** to call itself listeners, but it seems like there is no way to do that because I've got an app crashed. ***How could I call the listener itself from an 'else' statement? Or is there a better way to perform such actions?***

UPD: here is a code of the function

```
private fun validatePermissions() {
    Dexter.withActivity(this)
            .withPermissions(permissions)
            .withListener(object : MultiplePermissionsListener {

                override fun onPermissionsChecked(report: MultiplePermissionsReport?) {

                    when (report?.areAllPermissionsGranted()) {
                        true -> isPermissionsGranted = true
                        false -> isPermissionsGranted = false
                    }
                    if (report?.isAnyPermissionPermanentlyDenied == true){
                        AlertDialog
                            .Builder(this@MainActivity)
                            .setTitle(R.string.permAlertDialogTitle)
                            .setMessage(R.string.permissionsPermanentlyDenied)
                            .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok) { _, _ -> }
                            .show()
                    }

                }

                override fun onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(permissions: MutableList<PermissionRequest>?, token: PermissionToken?) {
                    AlertDialog
                            .Builder(this@MainActivity)
                            .setTitle(R.string.permAlertDialogTitle)
                            .setMessage(R.string.permissionsAlertMessage)
                            .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok) { _, _ -> token?.continuePermissionRequest() }
                            .show()
                }
            })
            .check()
}
```

Comment: What exactly does `validatePermissions()` do? Can you share the code of this function and also the stack trace?

Comment: @Tenfour04 added a function code, don't have any errors in logcut

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is, just call `changeBackground()` from the permissions results callback, if the permission was granted.

```
fun changeBackgroundIfPossible(): {
    if(isPermissionsGranted){
        changeBackground()
    } else{
       validatePermissions()
    }
}

// Where the permission results are received: 
fun onRequestPermissionsResult(...) {
     // Check if permission was granted and:
     changeBackground()
}
```

Calling a listener from itself is generally a bad idea, and quite often can be avoided.

In your case, consider that when you called `ib_selectBackgroundImg.callOnClick()` right after `validatePermissions()` it will be called again (for the permission hasn't been given yet), and called again and again, ad infinitum.

Set a breakpoint or some logs and you'll realize this.

Comment: It works this way, but I thought there is another good way) Thanks a lot, I'll use this constraction.